# 404 trying to connect to KnowledgeTree WebDav

Tags: sharepoint, webdav

Perhaps someone has run into this before and could help me.  I have an old KnowledgeTree community edition that is on a CentOS Virtual Machine.  I need to be able to download documents from it folder by folder (i.e. Department by Department) and then upload those folders and documents into SharePoint as part of a migration process.

I've done this successfully before about a year ago with some other folders using the WebDav functionality of KnowledgeTree and SharePoint but now when trying to connect to the KT WebDav I'm getting a 404.  At first I thought this was happening because the certificates had expired but I've since updated them and I still get this error.  From within KT it displays the link that I should be using (https://kt.server.com/ktwebdav/ktwebdav.php).  I've tried creating a network location in windows with this link and I've tried connecting to it using the WebDAV option in GoodSync.  Both give the 404.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: I've powered on an old XP box because that's the lat time I remember it working and sure enough, WebDav via the old XP box work but I still get a 404 when I try to access WebDav via my Windows 7 Desktop.  Is there an option I need to turn off in 7?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what happened but it's working all the sudden on my Windows 7 machine via Map Network Drive.

Maybe a restart of the computer did the trick??